# Remove a view from the back history - Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

Anyone knows how to remove a view from the back history (or navigation stack) in ionic2?

In Ionic 1 I solved this with

```
this.$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
  disableAnimate: true, 
  disableBack: true
});
```

Would be really useful, for example, to fully remove the login page of my application from the history once a successfully login was performed.

Just not showing the back button isn't enough in such case, since Android terminals got their own physical back button on the devices.

I tried, after my login function returned a successful promise and before pushing the next page in the stack:

```
this.navController.pop();
```

or

```
this.navController.remove(this.viewCtrl.index);
```

but unfortunately both weren't successful :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

obrejacatalin on the https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-disable-back-in-ionic2/57457 found the solution

```
this.nav.push(TabsPage).then(() => {
  const index = this.nav.getActive().index;
  this.nav.remove(0, index);
});
```

so I guess it's important to push the next page first, wait for the promise answer and then remove the current view

Comment: This doen't really reply to OP's question: he was asking for removing "a page" not all of them.

Comment: Well yes it only remove one page and furthermore I'm the OP and I did answer my own question, so yes it definitely solved my question ;)

Comment: @DavidDalBusco had a laugh at this

Answer (score 17):

To remove one backview you need to use startIndex and count of pages to remove from stack.

```
    this.navCtrl.push(NextPage)
    .then(() => {
      const startIndex = this.navCtrl.getActive().index - 1;
      this.navCtrl.remove(startIndex, 1);
    });
```

See this document for more options like removeView(viewController):
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#remove

Comment: You're awesome !

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue with `Ionic 3`.
So, only two steps to reset history:

```ts
// ...
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }
// ...
this.navCtrl.setRoot(NewPageWithoutPrev);
this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
// ...
```

Links:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#setRoot
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot

Comment: The `popToRoot` call wasn't necessary for me. In addition, you can pass NavOptions to setRoot, such as `animate: true` and `direction: "forward"` to make it animate smoothly to the new root.

Comment: Can confirm, only `setRoot` is needed to clear history and start fresh page