# hideBackButton attribute hides the menuToggle button too

Tags: ionic2

**The Problem**

I push the **Root Page** to **Page2** that supports a side menu, the issue is that when it opens **Page2** it shows the **back button** and hides the **menu button** for that I've tried to add `hideBackButton` to **Page2** in order to see the **menu button** but I both the **back button** and  **menu button** disappeared!

Here is my current code:

```
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton>
       <button menuToggle start>
       <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
       </button>
 </ion-navbar>
```

The expected behavior should be:

Should hide the **back button**, and show the **menu button**.

Ionic Version:

Ionic2

Comment: Could you please add more code to see what could be happening? Because I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i4xHIu?p=preview) with the posted code and works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that following that way; however what you can do is to do a `setRoot` instead of pushing from the root to Page2

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use following instead of your code:**

```
<ion-toolbar hideBackButton>
       <button menuToggle start>
       <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
       </button>
 </ion-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow the "back" action on your Page2, and since you face a problem hiding the button, why not removing your root page from the history stack before accessing your Page2?

In such a case, the "back" action not gonna be allowed and the "back" button not gonna be displayed too.

About how to remove a page from the history stack before pushing another page, you could have a look at:

[Remove a view from the back history - Ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369274/remove-a-view-from-the-back-history-ionic2)